# How can I access all values of a multi-value field?

Tags: 8

I am using Drupal 8 for a project for learning purposes. In my case I want to access to a field which contains multiple values, but I can't find how to do that. For example for a single value field I can access it like this:

```
kint($variables['node']->field_name->value);
```

But how can I get all the values of field which allows more than one value?

Comment: `contain more than user` you mean more than 1 value?

Comment: yeep that's it ::)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get all values of a multi-value field:

```
$node = $variables['node'];
$values = array();
foreach ($node->field_name->getValue() as $value) {
  if (!empty($value['value'])) {
    $values[] = $value['value'];
  }
}
```

OR

```
$node = $variables['node'];
$values = array();
foreach ($node->field_name as $item) {
  if (!empty($item->value)) {
    $values[] = $item->value;
  }
}
```